# How to erase all non-letter characters before first letter (R vector of character strings)

Tags: regex, r

I have a vector of character strings:

```
 cities <- c("London", "001 London", "Stockholm", "002 Stockholm")
```

I need to erase anything in each string that precedes first letter so that I would have:

```
 cities <- c("London", "London", "Stockholm", "Stockholm")
```

I've tried e.g. this

```
 cities <- sub("^.*?[a-zA-Z]", "", cities)
```

but that erases the first letter too, which I don't want to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
cities <- c("London", "001 London", "Stockholm", "002 Stockholm")
gsub("^\\P{L}*", "", cities, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/NBCUpn)

The `^\\P{L}*` regex means:

- `^` - Assert the beginning of the string
- `\\P{L}*` - 0 or more characters other than a letter.

This solution is preferable if you have city names starting with Unicode letters.

Answer (score 3):

Use a negated character class to match all the non-alphabetic characters which exists at the start.

```
cities <- sub("^[^a-zA-Z]*", "", cities)
```

or

Use capturing group to capture the first letter character.

```
cities <- sub("^.*?([a-zA-Z])", "\\1", cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete number:

```
 gsub('\\d+','',cities)
 [1] "London"     " London"    "Stockholm"  " Stockholm"
```

Comment: Almost good. I want those preceding white spaces to go as well.

Comment: gsub('\\d+\\s','',cities)

Comment: @ShenglinChen: That will work in this concrete case, but what if there are other non-letter symbols before the words? Dots, periods, brackets... Anyway, it will be a valid answer, please modify your answer with the gsub in the above comment.